# What is maximum size user can upload from mobile/tablet?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, browser, mobile-safari

I am working on the web-application which is supporting a upload of 2 GB in size. We have used the chunking logic to upload the file from browser to server.

The functionality is working fine in Desktop browser but when it comes to the mobile/tablet browser, we are unable to upload the file of mentioned size. We were able to upload max 1 GB file from the device browser.

Can anyone please help me understand why this issue appearing?

P.S. - The same is the case with Google Drive too.

Comment: Via WiFi or cellular data?

Comment: We are testing over WiFi

Comment: And the issue comes with both iOs & Android?

Comment: Yeap. I was testing on Nexus 9 and it got crashed